# How to cast String into Int and Long?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

In `Java` we use

```
Integer.valueOf(str)
```

and

```
Long.valueOf(str)
```

to get the `integer` but how can we do the same in `Kotlin`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just use [`toInt`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html), [`toLong`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-long.html), and similar conversion extensions.

For example:

```
val i: Int = str.toInt()
val l: Long = str.toLong()
```

There's also [`toIntOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int-or-null.html), etc. in case your strings might not be valid numbers:

```
val i: Int? = str.toIntOrNull()
```

Comment: Or `val i = str.toIntOrNull() ?: 0`

Comment: `fun String.toIntOrElse(defaultValue: Int) :Int = toIntOrNull() ?: defaultValue` usage: `val i = str.toIntOrElse(0)`

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin has extension methods for String class that do the same but more elegantly.

```
str.toInt()
str.toLong()
```

Note that you can write [extension methods](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) yourself as well.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin define [extension](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) function in [StringNumberConversions.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/StringNumberConversions.kt) like [toInt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/StringNumberConversions.kt#L113), [toLong](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/StringNumberConversions.kt#L141) etc. These functions internally invoke standard java function like 
`java.lang.Integer.parseInt(...)` or `java.lang.Long.parseLong(...)`

You can use them like :

```
"123".toInt()
"123".toLong()
```

Answer (score 1):

These are Extension methods available for `Strings` to parse in KOTLIN:

```
    str.toBoolean()
    str.toInt()
    str.toLong()
    str.toFloat()
    str.toDouble()
    str.toByte()
    str.toShort()
```

Answer (score 1):

it is better to

```
val str = ""
val quotaInteger = str.toDouble().toInt()
```

cos sometime end give us like "123.22", if we use toInt(), it will throw out NumberFormatException